# D3 how to curve segments when using `line.defined()`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using two paths here to indicate the present and missing data. I am drawing the solid line path on top of the dotted line path to achieve this. If I pass the data unaltered to the `dottedLinePath` it draws a continuous curved line, however, if I add `.defined(x => x.value !== null` to it, the lines of the defined data become straight with no curve. How can I get the path with `line.defined(x => x.value !== null)` to follow the same curve?

```
<div className="position-relative" style={{ width, height }}>
  <svg className="position-absolute" width={width} height={height}>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id={areaGradientId} x1={0} y1={0} x2={0} y2={1}>
        <stop offset="0%" stopColor={color} stopOpacity={0.25} />
        <stop offset="100%" stopColor={color} stopOpacity={0} />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g transform={`translate(${padding.left},${padding.top})`}>
      <path d={area(data) || ''} fill={`url(#${areaGradientId})`} />

      <path
        d={dashedLine(data) || ''}
        fill="none"
        stroke={color}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeDasharray="6, 4"
      />
      <path
        d={line(data) || ''}
        fill="none"
        stroke={color}
        strokeWidth={3}
      />

      {data.map(d =>
        !d.value ? (
          <rect
            width={6}
            height={11}
            key={Number(d.start_date)}
            className="text-white"
            x={x(d.start_date)}
            y={y(d.value as number)}
            fill={color}
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth={2}
          />
        ) : (
          <circle
            key={Number(d.start_date)}
            className="text-white u-mb-16"
            cx={x(d.start_date)}
            cy={y(d.value)}
            r={radius}
            fill={color}
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth={2}
          />
        ),
      )}
    </g>
  </svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a mouthful, but you can give the line a custom stroke-dasharray to draw gaps for missing data. I think the following is generic enough to use for your example as well.

```js
const margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  },
  width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const data = d3.range(10).map(i => ({
  x: i,
  y: Math.random()
}));

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, data.length - 1])
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => x(d.x))
  .y(d => y(d.y))
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

function getLengthAtPoint(targetX, node, length) {
  let result, currentX = node.getPointAtLength(length).x,
    previousLength;
  while (Math.abs(currentX - targetX) > 1) {
    length += (targetX - currentX);
    currentX = node.getPointAtLength(length).x;
  }
  return length;
}

function getStroke(data) {
  // Get the total length
  const totalLength = this.getTotalLength();

  // We find all places where the next value is undefined
  // And follow that until the first defined value
  const isDefined = d => ![2, 5, 6, 7].includes(d.x);

  let currentLength = 0,
    defined = true,
    strokeDasharray = "";
  data.forEach((d, i) => {
    if (!isDefined(d)) {
      if (defined) {
        // This is the first undefined piece, mark the previous point as
        // the last one
        defined = false;
        const newLength = getLengthAtPoint(x(data[i - 1].x), this, currentLength);

        // Add a dotted line until `newLength`
        while (newLength - currentLength > 10) {
          strokeDasharray += "5 5 ";
          currentLength += 10;
        }

        // We have a few pixels left
        if (newLength - currentLength > 5) {
          // Add an interrupted dotted line
          currentLength += 5;
          strokeDasharray += "5 " + (newLength - currentLength) + " ";
        } else {
          strokeDasharray += (newLength - currentLength) + " 0 ";
        }

        currentLength = newLength;
      }
    } else {
      if (!defined) {
        // This is the first defined piece
        defined = true;
        const newLength = getLengthAtPoint(x(data[i - 1].x), this, currentLength);

        // Add a gap until `newLength`
        strokeDasharray += "0 " + (newLength - currentLength) + " ";
        currentLength = newLength;
      }
    }
  });
  return strokeDasharray;
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line)
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", getStroke);
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffab00;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer. My question is about how to use `line.undefined` with two paths laying on top of each other tho. This answer could work, but it is just too verbose. the `undefined` part of my question is what is breaking the curve. I am simply wondering how to make those straight segments curve again so that it lays on top of the dotted line covering up the defined data and only exposing the undefined data with the gaps in the defined line.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible in the way you want it, because not knowing the following point makes it impossible to know the angle at which to approach the point

Comment: I understand that my answer is verbose, but it would actually be easier to alternatively draw a solid and a dashed line, than to draw a dashed line with gaps